# Can Someone Explain This Metal Flashing Under Tub/Shower Insert?

Tags: flooring, remodeling, flashing

We moved into a model home ten years ago, and we’ve decided to start making some upgrades.

Currently, I’m removing the existing flooring on our second floor in order to replace it with vinyl laminate planks throughout. The subfloor is wood, and most of the flooring was carpet in the bedrooms and hallway.

The two bathrooms had ceramic tile adhered to cement backer board (a pain to remove, but it’s basically done…). When removing the carpet on the other side of the hall bath, I noticed thin metal sheeting nailed to the floor that went under the existing wall and trim, but there is an air return vent there, so I assumed it was connected somehow and ignored it.

Now that I’ve removed the tile and backer board, I see the same metal sheeting sticking out under the walls/floor trim by about a foot on either side of the tub insert. Can anyone explain what the metal is for please? Can/should I remove it before laying the new flooring, or is it something that should remain under the new flooring?

I’m not completely familiar with housing construction, but I feel confident doing projects like this one. I’m mainly asking out of curiosity and also want to make sure I don’t mess with anything in hay I’ll regret later on…

This is literally my first post on Stack Exchange… yes, I know it seems impossible, but I’ve read a lot of good information on here, and I respect the knowledge of those of you who are skilled in the trades that I know little about.

Any help or information is much appreciated!

[image: Metal flashing under wall]

[image: Metal flashing under wall]

Comment: Full-size photos would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd speculate that it's someone's idea of adding a waterproof layer in case of any leaks, though I'm not sure it''s all that beneficial as such if the water just seeps out to the edge and then gets into the floor.

Comment: Is there a story above the bathroom's floor? Are there HVAC air intakes above these spots on the next floor up?